# SOLR Search for names with partial matches

Tags: solr

I have a SOLR server with a core of persons names in it, and I have now tried multiple configurations without finding the one that suits our needs the best.

Typical entries in the core are:

```
{
    "Post_code":"7001",
    "Full_name":"Ole Sverre Haugset",
    "First_name":"Ole Sverre",
    "id":3809194,
    "Last_name":"Haugset",
    "Full_address":"Some street 112, 7001",
    "_version_":1643841934565834759}]
}
```

We use the `Full_name` property to search for people. However, often, people don't know the middle name of the person they are searching for.

Right now, I would get a hit on this entry by searching for:

- ole sverre hau
- haugset
- ole sverre

but no hit when searching for `"Ole Haugset"`

Right now this is the config I'm using for this field:

```
<field name="Full_name" type="text_ngrm" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_ngrm" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
```

I have tried some other configs as well, without any major success. 
The last one was:

```
<field name="Full_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: The last version _should_ give you a hit when searching for just `sverre haugset`, as long as you're searching against the correct field. If you're using edismax as the query type (defType iirc), include `Full_name` in the `qf` parameter and just the query text in the `q` parameter. You can use `debug=all` to get debug information back about how the query was processed. Remember that you'll need to clear out the index and reindex the content after changing the field type to get any (proper) change in behaviour. Send meg en mail om du trenger mer detaljert hjelp :-)

Comment: Hey @MatsLindh, thanks for the reply. The issue Im struggling most with, and maybe I wasn't clear enough, is that I need hit on "Ole Haugset", with the middle name left out.

Comment: What @MatsLindh says is true if you aren't actually including quotes around your queries. That turns them into phrase queries, so you'll need to introduce [phrase slop](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#using-slop) in order to match when there are intervening tokens.

Comment: What query parser do you use? dismax or edismax should return results.

Comment: Mats and Scott are also right, do not search in quotes. Phrases are most of the time not what you want from a search.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I got it working due to them. Quotes was my problem.